# Trailhead SOQL challenge error

Tags: soql, trailhead

Getting following error when trying to submit.

> "Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:  There was an
>   unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check
>   from completing: System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception
>   on row 0 with id 0037F00000KZ8ExQAL; first error:
>   FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Hey You going to delete a contact
>   which doesnt has any Account associated : []".

Kindly help what this means.My code is

```
public class ContactSearch {

    public static List<Contact> searchForContacts(String s1,String s2)
    {

       Contact[] cont=[Select Name from Contact where LastName=:s1 AND MailingPostalCode=:s2];

       return cont;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This error has nothing to do with this specific piece of code. Are you reusing a Trailhead playground org from a previous challenge? It appears you have a custom validation rule in place that is preventing Trailhead's validation from working correctly.

You can fix this by disabling the validation rule on Contact, or restarting the challenge on a new Trailhead playground.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It helped. I had a trigger before delete that was causing error.